# Let $z_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. If $z_{n}^{2} \to \infty$ then $z_{n} \to \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. If $z_{n}^{2} \to \infty$ then $z_{n} \to \infty$.

How $z_{n}^{2} \to \infty$, then there are $N_{0} > 0$ and $M> 0$ such that
$$
|z_{n}|^{2} > M \ \ n \geq N_{0}
$$
Soon,
$$
|z_{n}| > \sqrt{M} \ \ n \geq N_{0}
$$
Is it ok for complex sequences?

Comment: Does it hold for non-real complex sequences?

Comment: @Surb Where is the error in my proof?

Comment: @Surb For your sequence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$. In $\mathbb C$ there aren't two infinities ($\pm\infty$), there is just one.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Where is the error in my proof?

Comment: @Surb It's usual, when working with complex numbers, to define $z_n\to \infty$ as $|z_n|\to \infty$, or equivalently, $z_n\to\infty$ in the Riemann sphere. So we have $(-1)^n n \to \infty$ (in the complex numbers context)

Comment: @MarianaCoub Your proof is correct.

Comment: @MarianaCoub This is one of those proofs which have all the right formulae, but its _logical_ structure is not clear. I would expect that you pick an arbitrary $M>0$ and then go to $M^2$ in order to use the fact that $z_n^2\to\infty$. (As there will be $N_0$ such that, for $n\ge N_0$ we have $|z_n^2|=|z_n|^2>M^2$, it will follow that, for _the same_ $N_0$, and for every $n\ge N_0$ you will have $|z_n|>M$.)

Comment: I understood. Thanks guys for the discussion. Thank you very much.